# Creating SQL Server in Amazon, cannot connect to it using Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, azure-data-studio

I've created a SQL Server in AWS, here is the screenshot.

[image]

Then, I've pasted the endpoint, and try to connect using Azure Data Studio.

[image]

However; I couldn't connect to SQL Server I created through AWS.

Here is the error message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken) in /xplat/cfxfork/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 400
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in /xplat/cfxfork/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnectionFactory.cs:line 136
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in /xplat/cfxfork/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 96
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<TryGetConnection>b__1(Task`1 _) in /xplat/cfxfork/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 86
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<OpenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 314
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line 524
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

[image: [3]]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the database's security group:

[image]

Then add the following inbound rule:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

For Server name, enter the DNS name and port number of your DB Instance, separated by a comma.
Important:Change the colon between the DNS name and port number to a comma.

For example, your server name should look like the following.

database-2.cg034hpkfake.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433

Comment: I've separated DNS name and port number by a comma now, but still I didn't work